# Clear the prefix edit text value

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I Am trying to append the prefix **₹** with the entered edit text . It's working perfectly with the below code. But the problem is am not able to clear the prefix text **₹** when i press the cancel button. I want ₹ to be cleared as well when keyboard cancel button is pressed so that i can see the edit text hint again

Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
        editText.setText("");
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    if(!editText.getText().toString().startsWith("₹**₹**")){
                        editText.setText("₹**₹**"); // not able to use that sign , so that's why those asterisk. It's actually just ₹ 
                        Selection.setSelection(editText.getText(), editText.getText().length());

                    }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[Edit text value plus prefixed with dollar sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOJ4K.png)

[in this picture , i want to clear the sign when pressing the cancel button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IKjq.png)

Comment: prefix is user to fix not to remove/clear, therefore don't go in against.

Comment: @Mohan did you get solution??

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Accepted your answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set some Boolean flag while clicking your Cancel button & check that flag value inside the `afterTextChanged` method.

1. Declare `boolean isCancel = false;`
2. Your cancel button click listener

   ```
   btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           isCancel = true;
           editText.setText("");
       }
   });
   ```
3. Change afterTextChanged

   ```
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
       if(!isCancel) {
           if(!editText.getText().toString().startsWith("₹**₹**")){
               editText.setText("₹**₹**");
               Selection.setSelection(editText.getText(), editText.getText().length());
           }
       } else {
           isCancel = false;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

What does the cancel button do? Does it remove all the text from the EditText?
If so, you could check in the `afterTextChanged` method if the text in the EditText is empty. Only if it is not empty, add the sign. Your method could look like this:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if(!editText.getText().toString().startsWith("₹**₹**")){
        editText.setText("₹**₹**"); // not able to use that sign , so that's why those asterisk. It's actually just ₹ 
        Selection.setSelection(editText.getText(), editText.getText().length());

    } else {
        // The text starts with the sign, if it is equal to it, set the text to be empty
        if(editText.getText().toString().equals("₹**₹**")){
            editText.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure this could be refactored to a cleaner solution but this should work for you.

The problem you have to deal with is the following: By cleaning the text in the `EditText` you are changing the text and this triggers the `addTextChangedListener` methods.

Comment: It removes all the entered text after pressing the keyboard cancel button but not the ₹ sign. I want that to be removed as well so that i can see the hint .

Comment: Ok then the solution described will fit